I'm trying to install ComfyUI and I'm getting the following problem ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
(Comfyui) E:\Comfyui\ComfyUI>python main.py --directml
Using directml with device:
Total VRAM 1024 MB, total RAM 16316 MB
pytorch version: 2.2.1+cpu
Set vram state to: NORMAL_VRAM
Device: privateuseone
VAE dtype: torch.float32
Using sub quadratic optimization for cross attention, if you have memory or speed issues try using: --use-split-cross-attention Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 76, in <module>
import execution
File "E:\Comfyui\ComfyUI\execution.py", line 11, in <module>
import nodes
File "E:\Comfyui\ComfyUI\nodes.py", line 21, in <module>
import comfy.diffusers_load
File "E:\Comfyui\ComfyUI\comfy\diffusers_load.py", line 3, in <module>
import comfy.sd
File "E:\Comfyui\ComfyUI\comfy\sd.py", line 18, in <module>
from . import model_detection
File "E:\Comfyui\ComfyUI\comfy\model_detection.py", line 1, in <module>
import comfy.supported_models
File "E:\Comfyui\ComfyUI\comfy\supported_models.py", line 5, in <module>
from . import sd1_clip
File "E:\Comfyui\ComfyUI\comfy\sd1_clip.py", line 3, in <module>
from transformers import CLIPTokenizer
File "E:\an\envs\Comfyui\lib\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
from . import dependency_versions_check
File "E:\an\envs\Comfyui\lib\site-packages\transformers\dependency_versions_check.py", line 16, in<module>
from .utils.versions import require_version, require_version_core
File "E:\an\envs\Comfyui\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from huggingface_hub import get_full_repo_name  # for backward compatibility
File "E:\an\envs\Comfyui\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\__init__.py", line 503, in __getattr__
submod = importlib.import_module(submod_path)
File "E:\an\envs\Comfyui\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "E:\an\envs\Comfyui\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\hf_api.py", line 45, in <module>
import requests
I tried pip3 install requests
(Comfyui) E:\Comfyui\ComfyUI>pip3 install requests WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -orch (e:\an\envs\comfyui\lib\site-packages) Requirement already satisfied: requests in e:\an\envs\comfyui\lib\site-packages (2.32.2) Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in e:\an\envs\comfyui\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.3.2) Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in e:\an\envs\comfyui\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.7) Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in e:\an\envs\comfyui\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.2.1) Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in e:\an\envs\comfyui\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2024.2.2) WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -orch (e:\an\envs\comfyui\lib\site-packages)
but it doesn't work
如果能用中文，谢谢

Running this command from the command line will solve your problem.
sudo pip3 install requests

